# About separable closure.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field and let $K(u,v)$ be an algebraic extension of $K$. Now if $K(u)$ is the separable closure of $K$ in $K(u,v)$, how to prove that any subfield $E$ of $K(u,v)/K$ is contained in $(E\cap K(u))(v)$?

Thank you in advance!